# Should I use dataTable or panelGrid? JSF

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

```
<table id="tbl" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" style="padding-top: 10px;width:100%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th width="20%">Emp No</th>
            <th width="15%">title</th>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="10%">shift</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th> 
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody style="cursor:pointer;">
        Yeh aik arzi tehreer hai
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I started to convert this code for my JSF app I found that I can use either `<h:dataTable>` or `<h:panelGrid>` because both are use here as an alternative of `table in html`.So first thing which I want to ask is what should I use here?
2ndly how can I handle `<thead>` , `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>`as I didn't find their alternate in JSF.So please can anyone put some effort to help me for this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h:dataTable>` is a good choice if you have (in your backing bean) a set of objects you need to display. For example if you have a List of object Employee (with Id, Name, Surname, etc.) then  is the best choice.

Here you can find an example of [how to use dataTable](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/04/hdatatable-java-server-faces-jsf/).

`<h:panelGrid>` is a good choice if you have layout various elements in an certain way. One case, is when you have to split the space in two columns of 80% and 20% respectively.
Though, 'I' suggest to use  (panelGroup) for this purpose see http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto

***Edit:*** With the `<h:dataTable>` For the header, footer, etc. you have to use the tag `<f:facet />`
see [Multiple Footer Rows in a JSF dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751860/multiple-footer-rows-in-a-jsf-datatable)

Comment: thx K - yea i know as for iteration purpose datatable is good but i want to know how can i handle this <thead> , <tfoot> and specially <tr> , <th> etc.Do You have any idea about this?

Comment: I hope the latter part of my answer can help you!